# How to change 0 to 1 in order to perform arithmetic operations, without UPDATE whole table

Tags: sql, plsql

**I have T1**, which is basically price-list, where headers are ITEM_NO; ITEM_NAME; ITEM_PRICE

And **table T2** -sold products, which joins T1 using ITEM_Number=ITEM_NO, and headers ITEM_Number, ITEM_TITLE, QTY, PRICE_TOTAL

My aim is to compare the price-list price with the real price paid per 1 item.

Basically, it should compare T2.PRICE_TOTAL/T2.QTY and T1.ITEM_PRICE

However in T2 table are columns where QTY=0 ->, in reality, there should be QTY=1 instead.

**So in order to perform DIVIDE operation, I have to change cells 0 to 1.**

Thanks

I have tried CASE statement but I think it is not the right tool for this.
CASE 
                 WHEN T2.QTY=0
                      THEN 1
                 ELSE T2.QTY
END QTY

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to fix the data? A 0 quantity sale seems like a mistake. Side note: unless the item name changes with the sale, `item_name` should not be in T2. It violates [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: yes sorry, columns edited, it was just simplified example. Well because table is very huge and I dont have permission to do so.

Comment: How is a quantity of 0 to be interpreted? What does a non-zero `price_total` mean when there's a quantity of 0?

Comment: what is the issue with case? will you be able to use decode() function? are you performing the divide in a query?

Comment: I think the case is fine. Although you can make a temp table. But temp table will add extra operation and slow.

Comment: Please explain why the case statement you posted is not the right tool for this; it's what I would do

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what `qty = 0` means.

If it's bad data, skip it.

```
select price_total/qty
from t2
where qty > 0;
```

If it means 1, use a case statement to interpret the data.

```
select
  case
  when qty=0 then
    price_total
  else
    price_total/qty
  end price_per
from t2;
```

---

Moving forward, you should fix the data (or convince whomever is allowed to do that to fix it). Then no work around is necessary now nor in the future for you or anybody else. This will avoid unnecessary surprises, bugs, and work.

If 0 means 1, update the table (and find whatever keeps adding 0 sales).

```
update t2 set QTY = 1 where QTY = 0;
```

If a quantity of 0 is some special version of quantity 1, add a column to store that special info, set it, and set quantity to 1.

```
update t2 set qty = 1, special_flag = 'whatever' where qty = 0;
```

If it's bad data, delete it (and find whatever keeps adding them).

```
delete from t2 where qty = 0;
```

If a quantity of 0 is correct and means means 0 then why is there an entry? What does it mean for a quantity of 0 with a non-zero `price_total`?

The size of the table doesn't matter, run it in the background. Assuming you're using InnoDB tables the `update` won't lock anything. If you aren't, use `update low_priority`.

Comment: Your solution really is best, but I think he just isnt allowed to fix the data. Probably an old established DB where someone messed up the data input and then just worked around it. Now the 0s are part of the DB and if you "fix" them, you mess up everything. I have a table containing SQL Queries that works with an in use application, but I had to spend many hours writing functions to fix up those queries so I can use them now in a different application w/o changing them in the DB.

Comment: @TineO This is what is known as the lava flow anti-pattern. The more folks work around it, the worse it gets. I don't know their situation, but I try to provide the option of not kicking the can down the road. http://antipatterns.com/lavaflow.htm